# Error While running first Native Script app

Tags: nativescript

I am having this error
**processing node_modules failed command Error: gradlew.bat failed with exit code1**
while running the app.
here is the screen shot of my command prompt

[image]

Comment: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/error-while-running-an-app/1439/4?u=pete.k - basically a faulty gradle wrapper package. Force a fresh download and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks **pkanev** for your reply.  How to Force a fresh download?

Comment: I believe I answered in the forum thread I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link mentioned in **pkanev's** first comment for the answer of this question.